# React.js - Fetching data from back-end without AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am in the process of developing a web application using Express.js for back-end and React.js for the view layer. Before React.js, I used EJS templating and the workflow of back-end was similar to this:

```
var express = require('express');

[code omitted...]

app.get('/get_some_db_data', (req, res) => {
    get_db_data((err, results) => {
        res.render('appropriate_template.ejs', { data: results });
    });
});
```

So far, I haven't seen a React.js application having this type of rendering in the back-end, instead I've seen lots of AJAX requests going on in `componentDidMount()` member function. I find the rendering approach above to be very intuitive and I am asking you if it is possible for the server to render React components with provided props from server.

My guess is that this is not possible and there is a different rendering concept going on with the "react.js server side rendering".

I was unable to find a clear explanation on the matter, forgive me if I've missed a source on this. Thanks!

**EDIT**
 I am not performing server side rendering, *at least for now*. I am performing AJAX requests through [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)

**EDIT 2** I now see that React.js has a different concept of doing this, namely the MVC model. The thing  I was asking for implies a view layer dependent on controller and hence challenges the MVC paradigm. A seperate view layer that connects to back end using AJAX seems a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [NextJS](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/), this does exactly what you want.